# execute python program inside django

Tags: python, django

I am new to django. I successfully created my first django site. I want to make web interface to a python program:

```
def func(a,b,c):
    return a*b*c
```

Input form fields: numerical values of a,b,c
Output: print func(a,b,c)

My python program solves some differential equations where the inputs are values of a,b,c,.. and output is a text file containing result.

Comment: OK. So what is your question?

Comment: django seems to be an overkill for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Create a form class. Write a template that displays the form and the calculation result. Write a view that receives the values from the form and performs the calculation. Read [the tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/).

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to pass arguments to Python from a template using Django tags. You can do it by combining it javascript and passing it to the server via AJAX or another method and then returning the result with a combination of Django template tags and javascript.

Please be more descriptive in the future. In return, the answers will likely be more specific.